# Is there a way to construct pages with components

Tags: django, django-templates

I am familiar with the concept of [extends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-extends) and [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#include) with django templates.

However, I am trying to build up pages with components (which relates more to the "include" approach). Unfortunately, some elements on a page should be added in the header of the page (e.g. stylesheets) and some should be added at the end of the page (e.g. scripts).

Is there a way to declare blocks (e.g. `{% block extraheaders %}<link...>{% endblock %}`) in the included files so they are placed in the correct region of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for the following setup:

```html
<!-- base.html -->
<html>
    <head>
        {% block css %}
            <link href="/css/bootstrap.css">
            <link href="/css/base.css"> 
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}

        {% block js %}
            <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
            <script src="/js/base.js"></script>
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

```
{% extends base %}

{% block css %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <link href="/css/home-page.css" />
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block js %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <link href="/js/home-page.js" />
{% endblock %}
```

...with the main point being that we can use `{{ block.super }}` to place specific resources into a parent template's blocks through [inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance).

Comment: I think the use you make of `{{ block.super }}` is pointless. The way `extends` work, you should not use it.

Comment: This is the recommended approach as per the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance). "If you need to get the content of the block from the parent template, the `{{ block.super }}` variable will do the trick.". Perhaps I misunderstood what you are trying to accomplish?